# Найти id родителя Javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код

```
<ul>Стойка настенная
<p><li value="100">1 метр<input type="number"/></p>
</li>

<p><li value="200">1.5 метра<input type="number"/></p>
</li>

<p><li value="300">2 метра<input type="number"/></p>
</li>

</ul>
```

Мне нужно получить `value` в `li`, например при вводе во второй `number` получал `value` 200

Comment: Пишите ответ в ответе, а не в вопросе

Answer (score 1):

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName('input')].forEach(input => 
  input.addEventListener('input', e=>
    console.log(input.parentNode.value)
));
```

```html
<ul>Стойка настенная
<p><li value="100">1 метр<input type="number"/></p>
</li>

<p><li value="200">1.5 метра<input type="number"/></p>
</li>

<p><li value="300">2 метра<input type="number"/></p>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
$("input").change(function(){ 
    alert(this.parentNode.value);
});
```